# play [1.2.5] running a server-side process

Tags: playframework

I would like to schedule a server-side process to call some code in my play framework.  The code needs access to the siena data-model and embedded database.  What is the best way to do this?  The controller may call the code, but that is password protected.  Maybe I need to open a firewall protected port for this process.  What might be an easier way to do this?

Comment: How about built-in scheduled job of play framework? http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.6/jobs#scheduling
Invoke your code directly within your application at scheduled time. You don't need to deal with any firewall settings or web request in this case.

Comment: Great suggestion (wish it were an answer though).. I'm using that now.  There are some bash scripts that run.  I guess I could invoke them from Java unless there is a better way.